# Recursively unhide base class members

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, template-meta-programming

I try to write a class that takes a tuple of functions as its argument and overloads `operator()` for all `argument_type`s of the function. Right now this looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct holder {
  T t;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t i>
struct overload_helper : public holder<T>, public overload_helper<T, i - 1> {
  overload_helper(T t) : holder<T>({t}) {};
  typedef typename std::tuple_element<i - 1, T>::type inner_type;
  typename inner_type::result_type operator()(typename inner_type::argument_type x) { 
    return std::get<i - 1>(holder<T>::t)(x); }
};

template<typename T>
struct overload_helper<T, 1> {
  typedef typename std::tuple_element<0 ,T>::type inner_type;
  typename inner_type::result_type operator()(typename inner_type::argument_type x) { 
    return std::get<0>(holder<T>::t)(x); }
};

template<typename T>
struct overload : public overload_helper<T, std::tuple_size<T>::value>
{
  typedef void result_type;
  overload(const T& t) : overload_helper<T, std::tuple_size<T>::value>(t) { }
};


int main() {
  auto all = make_overload(std::make_tuple(
                 std::function<void(double)>([](double i) { 
                 std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
                   }), std::function<void(int)>([](int i) { 
                   std::cout << "int" << std::endl; })));

  all(1); //fails
  all(1.0);
}
```

The problem is that the base class is hiding each recursive definition of `operator()`. Is it possible to recursively unhide all definitions with `using` or is the only way to have a templated `operator()` and pick the right overload with `boost::mpl`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `using base::operator()` in your template to *unhide* it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using overload_helper<T, i - 1>::operator()` in each `overload_helper` should do the job, so long they aren't ambiguous.

Comment: This seems to work and now I get "invalid use of non-static data-member" which suggests that something is wrong with the inheritance hierarchy. Thanks.

Comment: @pmr: you should probably accept this answer, and then move on to the next one if you cannot figure out what is wrong. The error you are getting is completely unrelated to the original question here. (BTW: that error usually means that you are trying to call a member function without an object, i.e. `struct test { foo(){} }; int main() { test::foo(); }` )

Comment: @David, this wasn't the case. My code had other issues and I worked them out first to confirm that Xeo's answer is indeed correct.